# Wordpress: Different Image Rotator on every page

Tags: wordpress, image-rotation

The situation:

- Wordpress based website for Veterinarian clinic
- Image rotator on frontpage, separate header image attached to every page

The desired situation:

- Image rotator with several images on every page

Currently it is possible to couple several images with a page, in the backend they are shown in the "Gallery". I would like to show these images in the rotator.

Before I engage in writing my own plugin to do this my question:

**Is there a plugin available that can rotate several images on every page?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

1. Using your current image rotator, you can create templates for your new pages (page-your-slug.php) and add different images to the rotator on each template file. These are created it your theme folder. [Read more here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages).
2. Second option is to use the [is_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) function. Using that you can write and if statement to display the different images. if(is_page('your_page')) { images }, rinse and repeat.
3. 3rd option is assuming that you want this to be more dynamic and changeable. Install the [attachments plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/attachments/). this will allow you to upload a variety of images to each page (or post), which you can then loop through in your slider - this method is probably the best.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer! I think I will go for the third option.

Comment: I ended up using the attachments plugin, it was actually just adding few lines of code to use the images in attachments as rotator images. Just accepted your answer, sorry for the delay :-)